# Program not breaking out of for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, break

It seems as if my code is not breaking out of the for loop if item>=32. i have checked with a debugger and the won does change to "True" when the value is 32, but then the loop does not break.

```
def check_if_won (grid):
 """return True if a value>=32 is found in the grid; otherwise False"""
 for row in grid:
  for item in row:
   if item>=32:
    won=True
    break
   else:
    won=False
 return won
if __name__ == "__main__":
 grid1 = [[4,2,32,2],[2,8,16,8],[16,32,8,4],[4,8,4,2]]
 print(check_if_won(grid2))
```

If run the program returns False

Comment: You are breaking out of the inner loop but not the outer loop. In any event -- why break at all? Why not just directly return?

Comment: Because it needs to return False if it's not True? Not entirely sure if this logic makes sense and I'm just missing the easy way to do this?

Comment: A function can have more than one return statement. As soon as you find that you should return true -- return true rather than break out of the loop and return true later.

Comment: Got it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are breaking from the inner loop but not the outer. But you can avoid a break all together and just return at that point anyway. This will solve your problem and create cleaner and easier to read code.

```
def check_if_won (grid):
 """return True if a value>=32 is found in the grid; otherwise False"""
 for row in grid:
  for item in row:
   if item>=32:
    return True
 return False
if __name__ == "__main__":
 grid1 = [[4,2,32,2],[2,8,16,8],[16,32,8,4],[4,8,4,2]]
 print(check_if_won(grid2))
```

Answer (score 0):

you breaking the second loop but not the first.
you need:

```
for row in grid:
 if won:
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, `break` only breaks out of the immediate loop. You can avoid the break and simplify a little by taking advantage of python's `any()`, e.g.:

```
def check_if_won(grid):
    """return True if a value>=32 is found in the grid; otherwise False"""
    if any(item >= 32 for row in grid for item in row):
        won = True
    else:
        won = False
    return won
```

Or more succinctly:

```
def check_if_won(grid):
    """return True if a value>=32 is found in the grid; otherwise False"""
    if any(item >= 32 for row in grid for item in row):
        return True
    return False
```